# IBM watson trade-off analytics javascript widget returns some unknown error

Tags: ibm-watson

I am trying to run the IBM Watson's Tradeoff Analytics widget to show the trade-off analytics graph in a webpage. The Tradeoff Analytics API is starting properly but when I submit the problem to the show the graph, I get some undefined error.
Here is the sample code that I am using the run the Tradeoff Analytics Widget.

```
function errorHandler(payload){
   alert(payload.errorMessage);
}

function onShowCompleteCB(payload){
    alert('show Tradeoff graph complete');
}
function onStartCB(payload){
    alert('sending trade-off problem');
    var problem = <problem-json>;
    taClient.show(problem, onShowCompleteCB);
}

var options = { 
    dilemmaServiceUrl : <tradeoff-service-url>, 
    username : <username>,
    password : <password>
};

var taClient = new TradeoffAnalytics(options , document.getElementById('watson_widget'));
var s = taClient.subscribe('afterError', errorHandler);
taClient.start(onStartCB);
```

I also noticed from javascript debugger that HTTP response to the last request returned the reponse header *WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="IBM Watson Gateway Log-in"*. Moreover I get the following error in javascript console *XMLHttpRequest cannot load . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.*

Can somebody help me out with what might be going wrong here?

PS: I have cross checked my username and password and they seem to be working fine through REST based API invocation.

Comment: are you trying to use the code in the client side? where did you get that snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you are trying to use the client widget. You need to have a proxy app that will receive the request and use your `username` and `password`.

On your client side you will need something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='DIV_ID'></div>
```

**JS:**

```
  taClient = new TA.TradeoffAnalytics({
    customCssUrl: 'https://ta-cdn.mybluemix.net/v1/modmt/styles/watson.css',
    dilemmaServiceUrl: '/proxy',
    profile: 'basic'
  }, 'DIV_ID');

  taClient.subscribe('afterError', function onError(){ /* on error */});
  taClient.start(function onLoad(){ /* on load */});
}
```

**Server side(nodejs):**

```
var tradeoffAnalytics = watson.tradeoff_analytics({
  version: 'v1',
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>'
});

app.post('/proxy', function(req, res) {
  tradeoffAnalytics.dilemmas(req.body, function(err, dilemmas) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err.error || 'Error processing the request');
    else
      return res.json(dilemmas);
  });
});
```

Above you will find an example of how to implement the proxy using `express` and the `watson-developer-cloud` npm module.

There is a full sample you can look in [github](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/tradeoff-analytics-nodejs/blob/master/public/js/index.js#L67)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The widget seems to be working with node.js app. But, my entire application runs on java runtime. Is there a way for the proxy code to be run on java runtime? If node.js is the only way to get the widget to work, Is there a way to make my java app send the tradeoff analytics problem to node.js app securely?

Comment: You can find an java example here: github.com/watson-developer-cloud/tradeoff-analytics-java I wrote it so let me know if you have questions.